# Python and CalculateField

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3, field-calculator

I am having trouble with using Python together with my gp.Calculatefield tool in my python script, and I am not sure why..
Heres the code (UPDATED)

```
import arcgisscripting, os, sys
myTempWorkspace = r"D:\ScheduledTasks\Temp\TempWorkspace_HyMS_Licences.gdb"
#workspace set up
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
gp.toolbox = "management"
gp.Workspace  = myTempWorkspace
gp.overwriteoutput = 1

codeblock = """\
def calField(Location):
    fldLocation = !LICENCE_2_LICENCE_0_LICENCE_LOCATION!

    if fldLocation <> " ":
        return !LICENCE_2_ROAD_NAME! + " (" + !LICENCE_2_LICENCE_0_LICENCE_LOCATION! + ")"
    else:
        return !LICENCE_2_ROAD_NAME!
"""

try:
    #gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "[DWWEB_ADDRESS1] & \" (\" & [DWWEB_LOCATION] &\")\"","VB","")
    gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "calField(Location)","PYTHON","codeblock")

    print "Calculate Field - Success"
except:
    print "Calculate Field - Failure"
```

I am getting the following error in the pythonWin IDE

```
>>> Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp\CalcFieldTest.py", line 21, in ?
    gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "Location(newField)","PYTHON","codeblock")
RuntimeError: 
exceptions.NameError: name 'Location' is not defined
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
>>> Calculate Field - Failure
```

Now I am not sure why I am getting the error, I think I have done everything I should within the codeblock and on the gp.calculatefield line.

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1
So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the Calculate Field tool from its dialog with the same code block?  If not, then I think it is best to get that bit to work before trying to get it also working from Python.

Comment: I did try that, on a machine that had Desktop 10 on, but it was saying I had a syntax error on Line 2 of the codeblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To aggregate a bunch of the previous anwers/comments together, and add a few new changes, try this:

```
import arcgisscripting, os, sys 
myTempWorkspace = r"D:\ScheduledTasks\Temp\TempWorkspace_HyMS_Licences.gdb" 
#workspace set up 
gp = arcgisscripting.create() 
gp.toolbox = "management" 
gp.Workspace  = myTempWorkspace 
gp.overwriteoutput = 1 

codeblock = """def calField(fldLocation, fldName): 
    if fldLocation <> ' ': 
        return fldName + ' (' + fldLocation + ')' 
    else: 
        return fldName""" 

try:
    #gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "[DWWEB_ADDRESS1] & \" (\" & [DWWEB_LOCATION] &\")\"","VB","") 
    gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "calField(!LICENCE_2_LICENCE_0_LICENCE_LOCATION!, !LICENCE_2_ROAD_NAME!)","PYTHON",codeblock) 
    print "Calculate Field - Success" 
except: 
    print "Calculate Field - Failure"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its working perfectly, I think I need to do a bit more python. Thanks to everyone else for your help aswell!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need a colon at the end of your def statement.

> def Location("newField"):

**Edit (additional comments):**
You have a function called 'Location' and you appear to have a field also called 'Location'.  Is that correct?  You appear to be passing in the field !Location! as a variable to the function, but instead of a variable, you have a string "newField" (the quotes make this an string attribute and not a named variable), but you are not using this string.  Later on you create a variable called newField (no quotes and therefore not a string).  I'm not 100% clear what you are trying to do but I suspect you need to remove the quotes from around "newField" in the Def statement.  if you are creating a new field, you'll also need an AddField statement somewhere.

Comment: I've added the colon, and when I try to run it i get the following exceptions.NameError: name 'Location' is not defined
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: Please see my edits above

Comment: Doesn't the function also need to `return` something?

Comment: As Chad noted, replace `newField =` in your `if` and `else` statements with `return`.

Comment: Sylvester, You are correct the function was called Location and there is also a field (that has been created) called "Location". I have changed the function name to calField to save the confusion. 

Chad/nmpeterson - I have added "return", but still no go, the IDE says the function is not defined. I have edited my original question with the changes in code.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks on `"codeblock"` in your call to `gp.CalculateField_management`: with the quotes, you're just calling the string literal `"codeblock"`, instead of the string defined by the variable `codeblock` :)

Comment: @HalilSiddique - get rid of the backslash on the first line of your codeblock, not sure if that's the problem, but it shouldn't be necessary at the least.

Comment: nmpeterson - Changed, don't know why I didn't see that, it has changed the error though to "exceptions.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 3)"

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to CalculateField:

```
gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "calField(Location)","PYTHON","codeblock")
```

I think you need bangs around your input field in your function call:

```
gp.CalculateField_management(myTempWorkspace + os.sep + "LICENCE_3", "LOCATION", "calField(!Location!)","PYTHON","codeblock")
```

Also, it looks like you don't ever use your input argument anywhere in the function.